# How can I set a variable to divide and round up to 0 decimal places?

Tags: ruby

In Ruby, how can I do:

```
number_total = records / per_page
```

where `per_page = 100`, and `records = 1050`, and then round up so there are no decimals? So, instead of 10.5 it equals 11?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

**Edited following a comment**

```
number_total = (records / per_page.to_f).ceil
```

Comment: What do you want for `1.1`? It depends on that. `1` or `2`?

Comment: It can rather be on `records`, or on both. It doesn't matter where you have it. You just need at least either of them to be a float. Otherwise, you will have integer dividing an integer, which gives you a quotient. For example, 5 divided by 3 is 1 (with remainder of 2).

Answer (score 1):

@lulala Another root of all evil: cherry-picking results.

Run your benchmark multiple times.
I get the following:

```
       user     system      total        real
   0.120000   0.000000   0.120000 (  0.119281)
   0.120000   0.000000   0.120000 (  0.123431)
```

Which is a tie.

```
       user     system      total        real
   0.110000   0.000000   0.110000 (  0.118602)
   0.130000   0.000000   0.130000 (  0.127195)
```

Which suggests that `float_op` is faster.

```
       user     system      total        real
   0.150000   0.000000   0.150000 (  0.151104)
   0.120000   0.000000   0.120000 (  0.123836)
```

Which suggests that `integer_op` us faster.

Comment: FWIW it's usually a good idea to use the Benchmark#bmbm method :) https://apidock.com/ruby/Benchmark/bmbm/class

Comment: Great! I'm trying this again years later with Benchmark#bmbm and newer hardware and software. I'm consistently seeing that integer_op is faster by 0.05 seconds. Not close to a tie. Ten runs in a row with similar results

Answer (score 0):

Here comes root of all evil: a prematurely optimized method:

```
class Integer
  # returns quotient's ceiling integer
  def div_ceil(divisor)
    q = self / divisor
    if self % divisor > 0
      return q + 1
    else
      return q
    end
  end
end
```

The following benchmark code:

```
require 'benchmark'

$a = 1050
$b = 100

def float_op
  ( $a / $b.to_f ).ceil
end

def integer_op
  q = $a / $b
  if $a % $b > 0
    return q + 1
  else
    return q
  end
end

n = 1000000
Benchmark.bm do |x|
  x.report { n.times do; float_op; end }
  x.report { n.times do; integer_op; end }
end
```

Gives me this result

```
       user     system      total        real
   0.160000   0.000000   0.160000 (  0.157589)
   0.130000   0.000000   0.130000 (  0.133821)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't wish to use the float conversion, use % (modula) for the remainder items (which is how we would actually determine # pages when thinking about it logically).

```
number_total = (records / per_page) + ((records % per_page).positive? ? 1 : 0)

# (records / per_page) gets all full pages
# (records % per_page) get remainder of records after integer div
# + 1 only if remainder is positive
```

Answer (score 0):

```
number_total = records.fdiv(per_page).ceil

# https://apidock.com/ruby/Integer/fdiv
# fdiv(p1) public
# Returns the floating point result of dividing int by numeric.
#
# https://apidock.com/ruby/Float/ceil
# ceil(*args) public
# Returns the smallest number greater than or equal to float with a precision of ndigits decimal digits (default: 0).
```